# A hacker installed vnc & remote management programs on my Macbook

Tags: vpn, macbook, vnc, malware, spyware

A nasty guy I dated last year secretly installed a series of programs onto my MacBook Pro and I need help with allocating and removing them please. I haven't switched it on for 11 months so it's still running snow leopard.

Please note that I haven't opened my macbook for 11 months due to this problem. My questions are:

Here's what I know:

- He used a USB to install: remote management, Remote Desktop, remote installer
- He also put a file that looked like a PDF but it was a virus or malware that is an executable file
- He uses both mac and windows and also uses his Nokia as a device to access his victims remotely as well.

Ihad NO idea this guy was a fraud and had been jailed for fraud and extortion 6 years before I knew him and I only knew him for a couple of months. Please don't remind me how silly or stupid I am I just need help.

I began to realise something was up from the following:

- A little screen appeared when I logged onto my mac asking for the IP address I'd like to remotely connect to
- my mouse would move when I wasn't using it
- my wifi would be switched to 'on' when I'd have turned it off on a previous screen
- files and folders were recreating themselves and multiplying and wouldn't allow me to delete them
- activity monitor showed hundreds of thousands of files uploaded in the sent messages column
- I looked at the sharing settings and it had a connection under the 802.1 (not sure on the correct number) in the VPN or vnc settings
- when I tried to quickly back up my home folder to my external hard drive and any other USB I'd try it wouldn't allow me and would say "unable to transfer files as "flash is using the USB or ex hard drive"(or something similar to this I can't recall the exact words sorry). I also went and purchased a brand new ex hard drive and when I connected it and went to format it it said something like this "unable to perform this operation as the flash is using the ex hard drive"

Upon searching 'recent' in spotlight, the following appeared which I hadn't opened or used: (!!!!)

- terminal
- dropbox(I don't and have NEVER downloaded Dropbox)
- system settings
- the PDF executable file
- remote management
- remote installer
- keychain app
- activity monitor
- Apple remote "something"(can't recall)

Please note that I haven't opened my macbook for 11 months due to this problem. My questions are:

- has the program he's obviously installed able to connect a VPN or vpc automatically to my public wifi if I turn my macbook on?
- has he uploaded my files and documents etc to a Dropbox that he can access to view all my private documents off my mac?
- it's been 11 months since this happened, can he still acces me now when I turn it on?
- what terminal commands do I use to remove any vnc or VPN he's installed?
- how can I seriously remove these program's I've installed? And can I do it in safe mode through the terminal?
- how do I check for malware/spyware I believe he's installed? And remove it through terminal?
- there are 3 accounts on my mac so how can I do this so cleans all of them at once?
- I already tried to back up my data but i couldn't even get passed the formatting (I believe that was the malware or spyware installing something to do with dodgy flash on that ex hard drive I tried)
- can I fix my mac in safe mode and do this by using certain commands in terminal? Please help? thank you!

Comment: Hi Missmymac, and welcome to SuperUser. While I'm sure this is a concern for you, as it stands, you are simply asking too much here. The Stack Exchange format works best when there is a single, specific question which can be authoritatively answered. I count *nine* bullet points under "my questions are", and I'm not even going to consider what those could turn into. I suggest either (a) narrowing this down *a lot*, (b) reformatting and reinstalling the system from scratch, then restoring trusted files only and hoping for the best, or (c) hiring a professional to help you out.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my simple question is if anyone can help with terminal commands as I don't have access to mac stores or the original mac disk.

Comment: No simple commands to run - what you've described is way too complex for the simple Q&A format here, and you'd be best off finding someone to help you in person.

Comment: plug your hard disk into another machine that won't automatically mount it, maybe through a 'SATA-to-USB' device. then zero the disk.

Comment: I suggest that while you do everything everyone has suggested, you turn off your wifi router so that your computer cannot be accessed while you are taking steps to prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

Since doing a clean installation is not an option, I would follow below steps (Apologies for windows terminilogy, I don't use mac)

- Use an antivirus software and spyware removers to try to clean up at least the programs preventing back ups.If you are lucky , he would have used any 'standard' malware which could be detected by these.
- Take a backup of all important files. Make sure you do a virus scan later, before you connect the backup hdd/usb to any other computer.
- For preventing unauthorized programs from connecting to the internet and sending your data/remotely connecting, install a firewall program. You can choose only the trusted applications to send/receive data. (note: If there are resident viruses, there is a chance this could be compromised. At this stage you can't be 100% sure)
- Uninstall all programs that you are not familiar with
- Check what all programs get loaded automatically during start up, uninstall/delete the unfamiliar ones
- Do a clean installation at the earliest opportunity

Answer (score 0):

- Change your wifi password use WPA or WPA2 with a long password with numbers and symbols.
- Go to MAC store and buy a new blank hard drive and ask them to install it for you.
- Take your original MAC OS cd/DVD and reload onto the new hard drive.
- Update everything Have the MAC store scan and
- clean the original hard drive. Copy back only the files you need and
- reformat the old hard drive and use that as a backup.

Comment: Thank you but are there any terminal commands I can try? I live in a very remote ace now and don't have access to any of your suggestions but I do thank you greatly for those :)

Comment: First, I don't know MAC OS, but I have dealt with 100's of viruses/rootkits/etc and reformatting and reloading is always the best option.  How about FEDEX or UPS you can order from newegg.com  There are no quick fix terminal commands, yes you can dig around for hours and eventually find whatever but it is a long drawn out process that could take days.  If need be you can buy a new copy of MAC OS online relatively cheap.

Answer (score 0):

In a situation like this, it's vital to do reformat your disk and do a clean install, or better yet, as cybernard suggested, purchase a new physical hard drive. Anti-virus programs absolutely **do not** catch all types of malware, and you can never be sure you've discovered and cleaned everything that the fraudster may have done to the box. For your long term peace of mind, you want to be sure, and the only way to be sure is a clean install.

Before you begin, change your wifi password or turn off your wifi. You don't want to be on the network at the time you start the re-install.

Save any critical files on a USB drive.

Reformat and reinstall.

You might also want to consider reporting your credit cards stolen and opening up a new checking account, because it's entirely possible that information has been stolen.

Comment: I can't back anything up as I wrote that a notification appears when I either format a new ex drive or use any ex drive that flash is using the USB which I suspect means the virus is having its way with the USB in use